# Algorithm to compute cheapest path between two pixels in an image

Tags: optimization, shortest-path

I need to compute the cheapest path between two pixels in an image. The travel cost is specified by the user, and may depend on the distance between the pixels (including pixel values, which is treated as an elevation), as well as other factors. I tried Dijkstra, by scaling coordinates by a factor so I can have more search directions, but for any reasonable sized image, it becomes horrible expensive. I need more search directions because otherwise, paths may have the same lengths that should not have the same length.

A continuous model would look like, find $r$ such that

$$
\int_a^b f(\vec{r}(t))\,\mathrm{d}t
$$

is minimized, where $f$ is the image.

Notes:

- The image size can be large, 4096x4096
- The pixel values are floating point values. This makes any hash table based on pixel values infeasible
- It is sufficient to find *one* optimal (or approximately) optimal path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a variant of grid pathfinding(mostly used in game).

Generally, if your cost function has a good heuristics, [A star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) will give you an optimal solution with least time cost. But space waste is serious, so you can try [Fringe Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fringe_search). [This article](https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/grids/algorithms.html) gives a lot of good search algorithms.

But, if cost is literally a mess, best search algorithm is definitely Dijkstra(additionally, any cost must be >= 0, otherwise it's SPFA).

Another direction is tolerating some suboptimality. I searched a lot, and because games' maps are basically mirrors of real world, so many researches are based on uniform-cost. So here is some of my personal suggestion:

You can run depth-limit DFS to find an optimal node in given range and run DFS again on that node, until you reach the optimal. This is a simple greedy search(without heuristics). You must store visited node to avoid infinite loop.

Another way is running BFS first to reach target, and then try to *trim path*. The complexity varies based on your evaluating function. Firstly, based on your cost function, customize a evaluating funtion to select some "station"(like railway system), and then run search algorithm on each $(s_i,s_{i+1})$.

Here is a good overview [Fast-Grid based Path Finding for Video Games](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.702.1298&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

I am not sure if it's worth to solve a calculus optimization problem (which ignore grid topology structure!). So I only provide these "traditional" CS approaches. Hope this help you.

Comment: So basically unsolvable, or maybe I did something wrong. Dijktra requires gigabytes of storage of everything larger than 8x8 :-/

Comment: @user877329, it shouldn't.  Maybe you are implementing something wrong.  Dijkstra's algorithm should use space that is linear in the number of pixels.

Comment: @D.W. I found a bug: It is a bad idea to push a node again unless its total cost has been updated.